# Dimension of $R$ over $Z_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the dimension of vector space of $R$ over $Z_p$ ? I think it is $p$.
Fruitful suggestion on how to look at it would be great.

Comment: What are  R , Z_p for you? I'm afraid I know the possible answer...

Comment: What is $R$ here? The real numbers? How would you make that a $Z_p$ vector space in that case?

Comment: R for the real numbers and $Z_p$ the integers mod P (residue class where P is prime)  for the scalar field. Is there any problem with that? Please mention

Comment: How is $\mathbb R$ a vector space over a field of characteristic $\ne 0$?

Comment: With the usual addition, $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, because every vector space over this field is a torsion group, precisely an elementary abelian $p$-group, that is, a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is torsion-free, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: With even less technology: a vector space of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has exactly $p^n<\infty$ elements. These two objects live in very different worlds, and it's not clear how you'd like to compare them. The only way I can imagine getting the real numbers out of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is to take the inverse limit $\varprojlim\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ to get $\mathbb{Z}_p$, take fractions to get $\mathbb{Q}_p$, algebraically close to get $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$, metrically complete to get $\mathbb{C}_p$, then take norms to get $\mathbb{R}^+$. If you know a simpler way...

Answer (score 5):

A vector space $V$ over $F=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is, first of all an abelian group with respect to addition. But not any abelian group can be made into a vector space over $F$, for a very simple reason: for each vector $v$ you can write $v=1v$ (where $1\in F$) and do
$$
\underbrace{v+v+\dots+v}_{\text{$p$ summands}}=
\underbrace{1v+1v+\dots+1v}_{\text{$p$ summands}}=
(\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{\text{$p$ summands}})v=0v=0
$$
because $p\alpha=0$ for all $\alpha\in F$. Note that the same is true when $F$ is *any* field having characteristic $p\ne0$.

Thus $V$, with respect to addition, must have the property that $pv=0$, for all $v\in V$.

The abelian group $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to addition is torsion free, so it can't be made a vector space under any field of nonzero characteristic. The same technique shows that $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be made into a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

The structure of vector spaces over fields of characteristic $p\ne0$ is very strict: they are direct sums of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Conversely, such a direct sum is in a natural way a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn a field of characterstic zero into a vector space over a field of positive characteristic (keeping the usual structures in both), because then

$$1\in\Bbb R\implies \underbrace{1_{\Bbb R}+1_{\Bbb R}+\ldots+1_{\Bbb R}}_{p\;\text{times}}\neq 0$$

**But** if we had a multiplication by scalar and all the axioms and etc., then

$$p\in\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;,\;\;0=p=p\cdot 1_{\Bbb R}=1_{\Bbb R}+1_{\Bbb R}+\ldots+1_{\Bbb R}$$

which is a contradiction

Comment: A non elementary abelian $p$-group either. The field structure on $\mathbb{R}$ is irrelevant.

Comment: No, it is not irrelevant: it's *exactly* what in this very particular case makes the construction impossible. For one, you could possibly make a $\;1-1\;$ map between $\;\Bbb R\;$ and an elementary abelian $\;p-group\;$ of cardinal $\;2^{\aleph_0}\;$  and impose on $\;\Bbb R\;$ the structure of the elemen. abelian $\;p-$ group, and then you **do** have a natural vector space structure on this ridiculously cumbersome but valid structure on $\;\Bbb R\;$ ...

Comment: It's only the *group* structure of $\mathbb{R},+$ that's relevant. The multiplication is not required, much less $1$.

Comment: Of course, who said otherwise? The mentioning of field is because the OP mentioned "the real numbers", which usually comes together with all the pack.

Comment: Can we think about a vector space $V$ over $Z_p$ with dimension $P$ ?

Comment: Of course, @Quantumkid: there is one unique (up to isomorphism) vector space of dimension $\;n\;$ over $\;\Bbb F_p:=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ , for all $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ . It can be constructed either as a quotient ring of $\;\Bbb F_p[x]\;$ or as the set of all the roots of a certain polynomial in an algebraic closure of this field. I'm not sure though you've already reached that point in your studies.

Comment: I have just started doing vector-spaces even without any knowledge of group and other stuffs. Do there exist any other example ?